# Exception while inserting Image into Excel Cell

Tags: java, excel

I'm new in Java, need to add a comment image into Microsoft Excel cell
my code returns an exception, anybody can help ?
My code in Java

```
          public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            /* Create a Workbook and Worksheet */
            HSSFWorkbook my_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet my_sheet = my_workbook.createSheet("MyBanner");               
            /* Read the input image into InputStream */
            InputStream image = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/Excel/Jellyfish.jpg");
            /* Convert Image to byte array */
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(image);
            /* Add Picture to workbook and get a index for the picture */
            int my_picture_id = my_workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
            /* Close Input Stream */
            image.close();                
            /* Create the drawing container */
            HSSFPatriarch drawing = my_sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            /* Create an anchor point */
            ClientAnchor my_anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor();
            /* Define top left corner, and we can resize picture suitable from there */
            my_anchor.setCol1(2);
            my_anchor.setRow1(1);           
            /* Invoke createPicture and pass the anchor point and ID */
            HSSFPicture  my_picture = drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, my_picture_id);
            /* Call resize method, which resizes the image */
            my_picture.resize();            
            /* Write changes to the workbook */
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/Excel/Book1.xlsx"));
            my_workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
    }
```

it gives this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils
>       at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.addPicture(HSSFWorkbook.java:1575)
>       at app.App.main(App.java:39)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 2 more
>   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

how to fix it ?

Comment: You should either add dependency to `Apache Commons Codec` in the pom file or add this library to classpath

Comment: `commons-codec-1.10.jar` needs to be in class path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try in such a way also

```
final FileInputStream stream =
    new FileInputStream( "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/Excel/Jellyfish.jpg" );
final CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
final Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

final ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setAnchorType( ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE );


     final int pictureIndex =
    workbook.addPicture( stream, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG );


  anchor.setCol1( 0 );
  anchor.setRow1( LOGO_ROW ); // same row is okay
  anchor.setRow2( LOGO_ROW );
  anchor.setCol2( 1 );
  final Picture pict = drawing.createPicture( anchor, pictureIndex );
  pict.resize();
```

Comment: `HSSFWorkbook` has no `addPicture(java.io.InputStream is, int format)`. Only `XSSFWorkbook` has.